# Allow No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, nginx

how can I allow laravel `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested` ? Because when I try to `$http.get()` a certain url using angular.js I always get error about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, got it. I just need to add before filter on my application.

**filters.php**

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is a great idea as you are potentially opening yourself up to a lot of issues as well as anyone being able to use your API.  What url are you using in angular for your gets?

Comment: What you are doing is allowing cross-origin request sharing (CORS) meaning anyone anywhere can interact with your API.  You should only do this if your angular scripts are on another domain, and in that case, change the first header to `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <DOMAIN WHERE ANGULAR IS>`.  If everything is stored on the same domain, if you create a virtualhost in apache, something like `crowdproject.local`, your scripts can call `crowdproject.local/api` and you shouldn't need to set these headers.

Comment: after 2 hours of trying various versions this worked, thanks.